# nth-child. Create a div and populate it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function that appends a div (Base-Shirt)  to a div (Button)

```
<div class="Button"><div class="Base-Shirt"></div></div>
```

I then want the images to populate the (Base-Shirt) div. When I run the script the images are placed after the "Base-Shirt" div. Do you know how I would get them into the "Base-Shirt" and not after them?

This is what is happening:

```
<div class="Button">
<div class="Base-Shirt"></div>
<img class="2016" src="img/swatch/2016.jpg" title="Ruby_Red" alt="Main, Pique">
<img class="2017" src="img/swatch/2017.jpg" title="Khaki_Tan" alt="Main, Pique">
```

This is what I want to happen:

```
 <div class="Button">
 <div class="Base-Shirt">
 <img class="2016" src="img/swatch/2016.jpg" title="Ruby_Red" alt="Main, Pique">
 <img class="2017" src="img/swatch/2017.jpg" title="Khaki_Tan" alt="Main, Pique">
 </div>
```

Function

```
function parse(document){

//Product
    $(document).find("Item").each(function(){
        $(".Button").append('<div class="' + $(this).attr('name') +'"></div>');
    });

//Swatch    
    $(document).find("Swatch").each(function(){
        $(".Button:nth-child(1)").append(
        '<img class="' + $(this).attr('name') + '" alt="' + $(this).attr('alt') + '"  title="' + $(this).attr('title') + '" src="img/swatch/' + $(this).attr('name') + '.jpg">'
        );
    }); 

}//function parse End
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `$(".Button").children(":first")` which will land you on the div-shirt element

Comment: Thank you this works but is there a way to use numbers instead of words (1) not (:first)?

Comment: you could use $(".Button").children(":eq(0)") or $(".Button :nth-child(1)")  NOTE: the space between the .button and :nth-child selectors.

Answer (score 0):

use `children` and `eq`

```
$(".Button").children(":eq(0)"); //<-- this will get you the first children(start form 0)
$(".Button").children(":eq(1)"); //<-- this will get you the second children
```